# not working to update node of network graph

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i'm using highchart to draw network graph.
and i want to change node's color.

my code to update node is

```
highchart.series[0].nodes[5].update({color: '#ff0000'});
```

it seem to work, but i get error like this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at t.setNodeState [as setState]
```

i guess it's not working
when i update edge's node(has no "from or to" link) and move mouse on graph.

how i can update node's color?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dapB.jpg)

```js
const graphData = [
    {from: 'Root', to: 'Group1'},
    {from: 'Group1', to: 'Group1-1'},
    {from: 'Group1-1', to: 'file1-1-1'},
    {from: 'file1-1-1', to: 'asset1-1-1'},
    {from: 'file1-1-1', to: 'asset1-1-2'},
];
const nodeData = [
    { id: 'Root', color: '#000000'},
    { id: 'Group1', color: '#00ff00' },
    { id: 'Group1-1', color: '#00ff00' },
    { id: 'file1-1-1', color: '#0000ff' },
    { id: 'asset1-1-1', color: '#d0d0d0' },
    { id: 'asset1-1-2', color: '#d0d0d0' },
];

const highchart = Highcharts.chart('highchart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  title: {
    text: undefined
  },
  plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
      keys: ['from', 'to'],
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        enableSimulation: true,
                linkLength: 100,
        integration: 'verlet', // "euler"
      },
      link: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#B1B1B0',
        dashStyle: 'Dash'
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        y: -1,
        style: {
          fontSize: 10,
                    fontFamily: 'NotoSans-SemiBold',
                    textOutline: false
        },
        inside: false, // text 반전
        textPath: {
          enabled: false // circle 에 맞춰 text 곡선처리
        },
        linkTextPath: {
          enabled: false
        },
        linkFormat: '',
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          update: function(param){
            console.log('update', param)
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Root',
    id: 'Root',
        allowPointSelect: true,
    data: graphData,
        nodes: nodeData,
  }]
});

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  highchart.series[0].nodes[5].update({marker: {
    fillcolor: '#ff0000'
  }});
});
```

```css
#highchart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/8.2.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js"></script>
<button id="btn">update</button>
<div id="highchart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` feature doesn't exist for the nodes. It works for the points -  https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

However, you can change the point color in this way:

```
highchart.series[0].nodes[5].graphic.css({
    fill: 'red'
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0Lwuce7q/